# I have no sound on my laptop--Windows 10. Tough issue

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, speakers

Ok so I've asked this question on several forums but have had no luck. I snapped my headphone connector off in my headphone jack so my laptop constantly thinks there are headphones plugged in. It is in there good, its not coming out--trust me.

I fixed the issue once but I can't remember exactly what the resolution was. Windows did an update the other day and now I'm back with no sound. I feel like I need to disable headphone jack detection or something. I seem to remember realtek needing to be removed but I'm not positive about that. If I recall correctly I need to use the system default speakers and when realtek is installed that is not possible. Just disabling the realtek driver didn't solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You would be better off figuring out how to remove the broken stem.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. As I said, I know its possible to force audio through the system speakers--as I've done it before. I just can't recall how exactly :/

Answer (score 0):

Odds are in your Realtek Audio Manager (Should be in your system tray - bottom right of your screen), you can disable the headphone jack. When plugging in new devices, you can specify what device you just plugged in, hence the reverse is also possible afaik.